# how to read a preexisting database into to django

Tags: python, database

I have a database in MS SQL where we populated our data in this database. I am trying to write a web-based app in order to read that data and present it on a webpage. I know the data structure and model so don't want to migrate them since they already exist. Is this possible?

Also, is it possible for Django to write the necessary tables it needs in a separate database?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see this message. I tried to use it but since I was using ms-sql for my database it didn't work. I found out the problem was that the ms-sql driver was designed for Django 0.8 which for a weird reason it didn't work with Django 1.11. I was able to identify the issue but wasn't sure how it can get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

django has an utility called `inspectdb`, see more from doc: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/legacy-databases/